# Send dynamic string in AJAX data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have next problem:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/cart/add',
    type: 'post',
    data: { product_id:product_id, quantity:quantity, "option[30]":product_option_id},
    dataType: 'json',
```

I have an ajax function that must return key option[value] and it's value product_option_id.
My function takes three parameters:

```
function addTocartN(product_id, product_option_id, product_option) {
```

So i need to get data like this:

```
data: { product_id:product_id, quantity:quantity, "option[product_option]":product_option_id}
```

How i can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function addToCartN(product_id, product_option_id, product_option) {

  var data = {};
  data.product_id = product_id;

  var optionKeyStr = "option[" + product_option + "]";
  data[optionKeyStr] = product_option_id;

  ...

  $.ajax({
    url: ...,
    type : ...,
    data : data,
    ...
  });

}
```

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you so much!